# Symfony2 Pdf generation

Tags: symfony, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, proc-open

I need to generate a PDF, I use SpreadPdfGeneratorBundle, the problem is that this bundle use "proc_open" function which is disabled by my webHosting "ex2", I contacted them, they inform me that they cannot enable this function.
the PDF generation works well in the locale. Here is the code:

```
$html= $request->get('lettreheader');
$request->get('lettreContent').$request->get('lettreFooter');
/*$html = $this->renderView('GrcRelanceBundle:Default:lettreRelance.html.twig');*/
$pdfGenerator = $this->get('spraed.pdf.generator');
$pdfGenerator->generatePDF($html);
return  new Response($pdfGenerator->generatePDF($html),
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => "inline; filename='Relance client.pdf'"
    )
);
```

The message of the error is :

> Warning: proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons (500
>   Internal Server Error)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a lot of time lately looking at solutions for PDF generation. I had the same issue as you: I do not control what is enabled on the server, and cannot execute a binary on the server.

The best solution I found is TCPDF, because it's PHP only. There is a Symfony bundle to enable it:

https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle

I do not know how it compares to `SpreadPdfGeneratorBundle`, the generation is a bit tricky sometimes, especially for partial CSS support, but nonetheless I was able to generate PDFs correctly on the server.

Comment: Please, do you have any docs because the doc in github is not enaugh,  I need to generate the pdf from view and save it in a folder.

Comment: There is very view doc on the Bundle github, however this bundle is only a way to integrate TCPDF.

For my development, I used the examples which are here:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php